# Can we publish an Asp.net web application using VSTS online continuous integration

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using VSTS online and having a web application.  While doing Continuous Integration I'm able to build my project in the repository and able to apply triggers to build my app on every checkin done.

**Steps used:**
1. Get Source
2. NuGet Restore
3. Build Solution
4. Publish Artifact
5. Publish symbols
6. Copy publish artifact

In fourth step, my application is not getting published to the specified folder and while doing a release the artifact is empty and getting empty artifact error.

Comment: Can you share the detailed settings for "Build Solution","Publish Artifact" and "Copy Publish Artifact" steps?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you should adjust build task steps as:

```
1. Get Source 
2. NuGet Restore 
3. Build Solution 
4. Publish symbols 
5. Copy publish artifact 
6. Publish Artifact
```

Copy publish artifact task must ahead of Publish Artifact task, because step5 copy file to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` directory, and step6 publish artifact from `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

**Second**, for asp.net web application, the build results have no such directory `**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**` (`**\bin\Debug\**` or `**\bin\Release\**`), so you should specify the contents of Copy file task as `**\bin\**` or the detail type of files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, all the steps got success and got following warnings

Issues
Build
Directory 'D:\a\1\a\MaxChat-Artifact' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'MaxChat-Artifact'.
Directory 'D:\a\1\s\Publish' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'MaxChatPublish'.


for releasing the build we need published content of the asp.net mvc project.  We are building and publishing using above steps.  But where do my published content will get saved.